# How to make bash pointing to correct version of ruby

Tags: ruby

I have 2 version of Ruby on the system, but like to use version 1.8.6.
Could someone show me how to do this?

---

## /usr/local/bin/ruby -v

ruby 1.8.6 (2009-08-04 patchlevel 383) [x86_64-linux]

## /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby -v

ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

## which ruby

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

Thanks,

PL

### Solution:

I found solution at https://superuser.com/questions/137130/how-to-configure-installed-ruby-and-gems by adding 2 lines in ~/.gemrc file.
    Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use such an old version?

Comment: For some reasons, some of the scripts were having so much issues with newer ruby 1.8.7. So, I try to revert to older Ruby version to see if it works. Ac

Comment: Adding the following 2 lines to ~/.gemrc file seemed to solve the problem for me: 1) gemhome: /home/CHANGE_IT_TO_USERNAME/.gems 2) gempath: - /home/CHANGE_IT_TO_USERNAME/.gems

Answer (score 0):

Set it in a `.ruby-version` file in your project directory.  Something like:

```
1.8.6-p383
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your version of ruby using rvm, assuming you installed that version with rvm, like this:

```
rvm use 1.8.6 --default
```

Or if you had ruby pre-installed and want to use that version than use this:

```
rvm use system --default
```

Of course, remove the --default if you don't want it to be the default.

Seeing that you didn't install 1.8.6 with rvm, I would reinstall it with rvm, so you are using rvm consistently across all your ruby versions.

Answer (score -1):

You're not on the right forum, but the answer lies in the order of directories in your `$PATH`. Check your `.profile` and/or `/etc/profile`.